# Remove tap outline from anchor element on Android device viewed with Firefox mobile

Tags: android, firefox, mobile, outline

Firefox mobile on Android tablet places a default outline around an anchor element when it recieves focus with a tap event. I can find no way to remove it ie the equivalent of

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible through css for mozilla browsers.

http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/

Maybe you could bind a Javascript EventListener "onfocus" to the anchor with a callback which automatically blurs the element when it is focused. It's more like a hack, but it should do the job